# Combine multiple excel with specific sheet and column

Tags: python

I am trying to combine multiple excel file with specific sheet and column into one excel using python, but it comes with the error **AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'parse'**

Any wrong with my below code? Please advise on how to fix this error.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'S:\\19 Performance Analytics\ETL Data Extraction\\PyCr')


    # Define the path to the folder containing the Excel files
    path = (r"C:\Users\jiacheng.heng\OneDrive - Shangri-La Group\NOVA\Arrival Check Tracker\CT2 Arrival Check Report\2023")


# Get a list of all Excel files in the folder
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.xlsx")



# Create an empty DataFrame to store the combined data
combined_df = pd.DataFrame()
columns = ['Report Pull Out Date (DD-MMM-YY)','Property','Confirmation No.','Guest Name','Arrival','Departure','Rate Code','Source'
           ,'Arr. Transfer Type','Dep. Transfer Type','Status','Agent Initial','Remark','Completion Date','Completion Month','Received Month'
           ,'Arrival Month','Status','AHT','Pending Aging','SLA']
combined_df=combined_df.append(all_files.parse('Data',usecols= columns))

# Loop through each Excel file and append its contents to the combined DataFrame
for file in all_files:
    df = pd.read_excel(file)
    combined_df = combined_df.append(df, ignore_index=True)

# Export the combined DataFrame to a new Excel file
combined_df.to_excel(r"S:\19 Performance Analytics\NOVA\CT2 Arrival Checks.xlsx", index=False)
```

Comment: Your error message tells you where the problem is. 'all_files.parse('Data',usecols= columns)' results in an AttributeError since 'all_files' is just a normal list which does not provide any parse method.

Comment: Understand and how should I rectify this? I would like to combine multiple excel file with specific "Sheet" and "Column". 

All the excel file having the same table structure

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there:

```
# --Beginning of your code

# Create an empty DataFrame to store the combined data
columns = ['Report Pull Out Date (DD-MMM-YY)','Property','Confirmation No.','Guest Name','Arrival','Departure','Rate Code','Source'
           ,'Arr. Transfer Type','Dep. Transfer Type','Status','Agent Initial','Remark','Completion Date','Completion Month','Received Month'
           ,'Arrival Month','Status','AHT','Pending Aging','SLA']
combined_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)

# Loop through each Excel file and append its contents to the combined DataFrame
for file in all_files:
    df = pd.read_excel(file,sheet_name='Data') # <--modified according to comment
    combined_df = pd.concat([combined_df, df[columns]) # I got a FutureWarning that append will be removed in the future, therefore I replaced it with pd's concat method

# -- Rest of your code
combined_df.to_excel(r"S:\19 Performance Analytics\NOVA\CT2 Arrival Checks.xlsx", columns=[<columns of your choice>] index=False) # <--modified according to comment
```

Comment: Hello, this is work but I got few question to clarify

1. There are few sheet in my excel file and based on my previous code combined_df=combined_df.append(all_files.parse('Data',usecols= columns)), I am trying to refer "Data" tab, but with your code given it seems like didn't refer to any sheet tab and still taking the correct result?



2. I have filter the specific column but why others columns still appear in the new export excel file?

Comment: I updated the answer. The sheet pandas reads in seems to depend on the order of tabs. To be sure you can specify which sheet it should process. Also for ouput you can specify which columns shall be considered. I do not know why you had difficulties after filtering. How did you filter your data?

Comment: Saw the updated code. Based on the above code there are specific column from 'Report Pull out Date (DD-MM-YY)' until 'SLA" and in the final export excel result did come out with the additional column which from the original excel and not in my code columns list.. If there any issue with my code?

Comment: I see. I didn't undestand that your excel sheets contain more columns. In that case you can simply select only the columns you need for the concatenation 'df[columns]'. I updated my answer.